# Otimizar tabelas Mysql

Tags: mysql, desempenho, otimização, query

Trabalho com algumas tabelas enormes em um sistema que desenvolvi. Essas tabelas estão constantemente sendo atualizadas e às vezes a consulta se torna lenta. Algumas delas chegam a ter mais de 100.000 linhas.

Gostaria de saber com qual frequência devo executar o comando de otimização `OPTIMIZE TABLE` do Mysql para melhorar um pouco a performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nem tudo é questão de rodar o OPTIMIZE. Talvez você deva começar a dividir suas tabelas em tabelas menores, normalizar os dados, diminuir as queries, analizar a eficiência das queries (com EXPLAIN), etc.

A primeira coisa que posso sugerir é a de revisar as queries que são rodadas e ver se você precisa de todos os dados retornados. Outra ação possível é começar a expurgar dados antigos da sua tabela, deixando-a mais leve.

Depois o interessante seria você estudar como funciona a normalização de um banco de dados (especialmente deixá-la nas formas normais 1FN, 2FN e 3FN, apesar de também existir a 4FN, 5FN e Boyce-Codd) e ver o que é possível de deixar no seu banco de dados.

Quanto o MySQL, você também pode ver se vale a pena otimizar as tabelas (por exemplo, para InnoDB, mas depende bastante da característica das suas consultas) ou arrumar as configurações do banco. Outra coisa: será que a máquina onde está o banco de dados não está sobrecarregada com outros serviços?

Verifique esses pontos e veja onde dá pra começar.

Comment: Considero isso o complementar da minha resposta. +1.

Answer (score 6):

Segundo o site do MySQL, traduzi o que diz o comando `OPTIMIZE TABLE`:

> Use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` nestes casos, dependendo do tipo de tabela:
>
> Depois de fazer uma quantidade substancial de inserções, atualizações ou exclusões em uma tabela InnoDB baseada em um arquivo `.ibd` porque foi criada com a opção `innodb_file_per_table` habilitada. A tabela e os índices são reorganizadas, e espaço em disco pode ser recuperado para uso pelo sistema operacional.
>
> Após a exclusão de uma grande parte de uma tabela `MyISAM` ou `ARCHIVE`, ou após fazer muitas mudanças em tabelas `MyISAM` ou `ARCHIVE` com registros de tamanho variável (tabelas que têm VARCHAR, BLOB, ou colunas de texto). Linhas apagadas são mantidos em uma lista encadeada e operações `INSERT` subsequentes reutilizam posições de linhas antigas. Você pode usar `OPTIMIZE TABLE` para reclamar o espaço inutilizado e para desfragmentar o arquivo de dados. Após extensas alterações em uma tabela, esta declaração pode também melhorar o desempenho de instruções que usam a tabela, por vezes de forma significativa.

Site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Em resumo, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` só melhora o desempenho de uma tabela se ela é modificada com muita frequência, para reorganizar os índices, as estatísticas e reparar a tabela em caso de registros faltantes ou pendentes de alguma atualização.

Comment: Vlw Cigano... suas informações foram muito úteis.